# how to drag and drop two elements in the same table ( selenium java)

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, java

Both functions works great on its own. But when I put them together. After I drag and drop the first element, I can't drag and drop the same element in the empty table.

```
    import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
    import org.junit.*;
    import static org.junit.Assert.*;
    import org.openqa.selenium.*;
    import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
    import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions;


    public class practice {
      private WebDriver driver;
      private String baseUrl;

      @Before
      public void setUp() throws Exception {
        driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        baseUrl = "website link";
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
      }

      @Test
      public void testUntitled3() throws Exception {
        driver.get(baseUrl );


           //drag and drop first element         
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("xpath for tab 1")).click();
            WebElement drag1 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("element in tab 1"));
            WebElement drop= driver.findElement(By.xpath("emtpy table"));
            Actions action2 = new Actions(driver); 
            action2.dragAndDrop(drag1, drop).build().perform();

        //drag and drop second element 
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("open tab 2")).click();
            WebElement drag2= driver.findElement(By.id("element in tab 2"));
            WebElement drop= driver.findElement(By.xpath("same emtpy table above"));
            Actions action = new Actions(driver);   
           action.clickAndHold(drag2).moveToElement(drop2).release(drop2).perform();
 }
  @After
  public void tearDown() throws Exception {
   // driver.quit();
    String verificationErrorString = verificationErrors.toString();
    if (!"".equals(verificationErrorString)) {
      fail(verificationErrorString);
    }
       }
```

the empty table

```
  <div tabindex="10" style="position: relative; overflow: hidden; height: 
    159px; width: 766px;" class="v-scrollable v-table-body-wrapper v-table- 
     body"><div style="height: 0px;" class="v-table-body-noselection"><div style="height: 10px;" class="v-table-row-spacer"></div><table class="v-table-table"><tbody></tbody></table><div style="height: 21px;" class="v-table-row-spacer"></div></div><div tabindex="-1" style="position: fixed; top: 0px; left: 0px;"></div></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code for second drag and drop element you have mentioned **drop2** in your action but you have'nt declared the **drop2** anywhere.Instead of **drop2** you have mentioned **drop** in your second block of code. So update your code as,

```
//drag and drop second element 
  driver.findElement(By.xpath("open tab 2")).click();
  WebElement drag2= driver.findElement(By.id("element in tab 2"));
  WebElement drop2= driver.findElement(By.xpath("same emtpy table above"));
  Actions action = new Actions(driver);            
  action.clickAndHold(drag2).moveToElement(drop2).release(drop2).perform();
```

Try this will work.

Comment: hi there, i found out that the xpath was entered incorrectly. When I put two drag and drop together the xpath changes. I appreciate the time you took to response to my question!